# Scala transactional block with for comprehension

Tags: scala, transactions, persistence, dao

Getting stuck with a DAO layer I've created; works fine for the single case, but when needing to persist several bean instances in a transactional block, I find that I have coded myself into a corner. Why? Check out the DAO create method below:

```
def create(e: Entity): Option[Int] =
  db.handle withSession { implicit ss: Session=>
    catching( mapper.insert(e) ) option match {
      case Some(success) => Some(Query(sequenceID))
      case None => None
    }
  }
```

Queries that occur within a session block are set to auto commit, so I can't wrap several persistence operations in a transactional block. For example, here's a simplified for comprehension that processes new member subscriptions

```
val result = for{
  u <- user.dao.create(ubean)
  m <- member.dao.create(mbean)
  o <- order.dao.create(obean)
} yield (u,m,o)
result match {
  case Some((a,b,c)) => // all good
  case _ => // failed, need to rollback here
}
```

I could manually perform the queries, but that gets ugly fast

```
db.handle withSession { implicit ss: Session=>
  ss.withTransaction {
    val result = for{
      u <- safe( UserMapper.insert(ubean) )
      ...
    }
    def safe(q: Query[_]) = 
      catching( q ) option match {
        case Some(success) => Some(Query(sequenceID))
        case None => None
      }
  }
}
```

because I then wind up duplicating error handling, have to supply database, session, etc. all over the application, instead of encapsulating in the DAO layer

Anyone have some sage advice here for how to workaround this problem? I really like the concision of the for comprehension, Scala rocks ;-), ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, unless someone has a better idea, here's what I'm rolling with:

Since DAO to Entity is a 1-to-1 relationship, and ScalaQuery auto commits queries executed in a session block, performing multiple inserts on separate entities is not possible via my DAO implementation.

The workaround is to create a GenericDAO, one not tied to a particular entity, which provides transactional query functionality, with error handling extracted into parent trait

```
    def createMember(...): Boolean = {
      db.handle withSession { implicit ss: Session=>
        ss.withTransaction {
          val result = for{
            u <- safeInsert( UserMapper.insert(ubean) )(ss)
            ...
          }
          ...
```

At the controller layer the implementation becomes `dao.createMember(...)` which is quite nice, imo, transactional inserts using safe for comprehension, cool stuff.